# Polymer paper-card link

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, paper-elements, custom-element

I want to make paper-card whole element as a link. How to do it properly? I've tried in this link: http://pastebin.com/Ch453kvK. Is that the proper way to do it? Actually it change styling that I applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to acheive this:

**1.** You solution is correct if it works. You can also try to put the `<a>` tag inside the `<paper-card>` element.

**2.** Or you can catch the `click` event on the `<paper-card>`, set the `location.href` property.

```
document.querySelector( 'paper-card' ).addEventListener( 'click', function ()
{
    location.href= '#link'
} )
```

**3.** Or you can put all the content of the `<paper-card>` in a `<button>`, or in a `<paper-button>` and set the `location.href` property in the `onclick` handler.

**4.** As suggested by @Adamos42 you can use [Polymer events](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events).

Comment: I prefer to add a `on-tap="_jumpToMyURL"` so I don't need to remove the listener or querySelect the element.